# Infinite loop for clear action epic

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I use `redux-observable` to handle redux async action.

I need to clear module state by id.

This is my `clearModuleByIdEpic`:

```
const clearModuleByIdEpic = (action$: ActionsObservable<any>) => {
  return action$.ofType(t.CLEAR_MODULE_BY_ID)
    .map((action: IActionPayload<any>): string => action.payload.id)
    .map(clearModuleById);
}
```

This is my component method: call the `clearModuleById` action.

```
 private onClear(id: string) {
    this.props.clearModuleById(id);
  }
```

But when I click the delete button trigger the `onClear` click event.

It trigger a infinite loop for `clearModuleById` action.

Did I make come mistakes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are dispatching the same action from the epic that you are filtering on in that epic. This will always* result in infinite loops. You need to always either A) dispatch a different action, or B) not dispatch anything else in the epic after triggering the appropriate side effect(s).

It also doesn't look like your epic is actually doing anything but re-dispatching the same action synchronously. Epics in redux-observable are to allow you perform 1 or more (a)synchronous side effects for an action.

Generally speaking you should not re-dispatch the same action from an epic unless you are doing so with some form of escape hatch. This is effectively a form of recursion and all of the usual recursive problems apply. Failing to break out of the recursion means an infinite loop.

*There are exceptions, but this true 99.99% of the time.

Comment: Also want to add that this is probably due to a slight misunderstanding of how redux-observable works--your epics receive the actions *after* they have already reached reducers so as mentioned there is no need to re-dispatch the incoming actions. Conceptually, I like to think of your epics as running along side redux. They cannot swallow or otherwise prevent normal redux-stuff from happening, they can only listen for actions and optionally decide to emit other actions at some point, usually after performing side effects.